# I kept receiving Template Does Not Exist

Tags: templates, inheritance, django-templates, django-inheritance

**create.html**

{% extends 'base.html' %}

**views.py**

Def index(request):
return render(request, ''main/create'', {})

I kept receiving template does not exist .
Please help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `main/create.html`?

Comment: It is...Its a typo

Comment: I'm still receiving ''template does not exist''

Comment: Can you please structure the question better, include more relevant code, and add the complete traceback of your error. For example, in this case, having `settings.py` and your folder structure would be really useful. If in doubt check [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) from SO Meta.

Comment: I've rectified the issue....Thank you.